# Regexextract multiple <a> links from HTML

Tags: html, arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an extract from a description off a webpage which contains multiple links to other pages the whole string is in a single cell. The string below is along the lines of

```html
copy <a href="/sitelink1">Link 1</a>,<a href="/link2">Link 2</a>, <a href="/Link3">Link 3</a>
```

I would like to be able to use the regexextract function to pull the link URLs from the above string, it doesn't have to be that the all pull through into the same cell afterwards.

Managed to get the first link extracted using href="([^"]*) however having no luck getting the 2nd and onwards links. Already tried using lookbehinds with (?<=href=)(.*?)(?=>) but it seems Sheets doesn't support this in it's regex engine.

Open to using apps script to sort this if it makes things easier, just would love a solution as I'm at a wits end here.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lduQcHLhtZ6gSBmbNLkD0nz4rsAkJqsA4-AyBRtSXpg/edit#gid=0 has a sample of the data, thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, 
 "(?s)^(.*?)href=""", ), "href=""", 0), """(.*)", )))
```

[image]